# Quarkus ActiveMQ JMS

Tags: java, activemq-classic, quarkus

I have an ActiveMQ queue that does seem not seem to be supported by Quarkus. When I try to use the Quarkus JMS implementation described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/jms) I get the following error:

```
AMQP SASL header mismatch value 0, expecting 41. In state: HEADER0
```

I assume that this is because the ActiveMQ server does not support AMQP. The code I wrote to try and connect to the ActiveMQ server.

```java
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("inQue");
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        messageMap = session.createMapMessage();
```

While the above does not work. If i change it to using
`ActiveMQConnectionFactory` from ActiveMQ it works just fine:

```java
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("inQue");
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        messageMap = session.createMapMessage();
```

But if i change to the Quarkus version of `ConnectionFactory` it no longer works and I get the error above. So is it possible to solve this somehow? Or do I need to use `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`? If so, how can I get Quarkus to register my `MessageListener`? Right now, just to test, I write:

```java
      MessageListener listener = new MyListener();
      consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
```

But I would like Quarkus to do this when the application starts. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Which version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which version of ActiveMQ you are using you should be able to use the Quarkus JMS extension which is based on Qpid JMS and speaks AMQP.  The trick is that you need to connect to the transport connector that was configured to speak AMQP and not one that uses the native Openwire protocol which normally resides on port 61616.

The ActiveMQ [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/amqp) defines how this is done.  Essentially in your broker configuration you need a definition similar to this:

```
<transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Of course if using ActiveMQ Artemis this configuration would be different but you didn't specify which specific version of ActiveMQ you are running.

The error message you provided (If it is from the server logs) indicates that the client did indeed connect to an AMQP endpoint but it got something that it did not expect which implies something else strange is going on such as you are not using Qpid JMS but some other client since the initial byte of the expected AMQP header is reported to have been zero which is definitely wrong since an AMQP header always starts with the letter 'A'.

NOTE: Given the comments the error message in the question is likely from the client which would indicate the client read the normally sent Openwire header meaning the transport connector in play was an Openwire variant.

Comment: Thank you tim. I tried your solution and got the following error

java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [amqp] from the server.

I have access to activemq.xml file but I don't have access to the server code running the activeMQ instance.

Is there any way to find out the version from the configuration file?

Comment: hmm after looking through some logs it seems to be a rather old version of activemq running 5.2.. So i guess amqp does not work

Comment: 5.2 is horribly old and should be upgraded ASAP.  You don't have any options for JMS 2.0 APIs with a version that old.

Comment: Okey, thank you Tim, I will mark your answer as the correct one since I think if I can manage to upgrade it. It should work